# Issue with perl/cgi execution on Python http server

Tags: python, perl, cgi

I am trying to learn Perl/cgi and as a first step, I have installed Python cgi server and ran the first Hello World program on localhost.

However the server is simply giving the plain text file without executing the script at server side. Please see:

http://prntscr.com/4wnfxf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Web servers need to be configured to handle CGI programs in a special way. Sometimes they are configured to treat files in certain directories (perhaps /cgi-bin) as CGI programs. Sometimes they are configured to treat files that follow certain naming conventions (perhaps with the extension .cgi) as CGI programs. If the web server isn't configured in this way, then it will treat CGI programs in exactly the same way as any other file and will just return their contents.

It looks like you think that your web server should handle CGI programs in the /cgi-bin directory. But it appears that your web server doesn't recognise that directory as special and is just returning the contents of the file.

Without knowing more about the web server that you are using, it's hard to give much help. You should search the documentation of the web server for sections on "running CGI programs" or "configuring CGI". The answers will almost certainly be there.

Comment: Thank you, that helps... I am using http.server that comes with the python installation. I run the server program from command prompt using :  python -m http.server 8000

Comment: Please don't post screenshots, *especially* if it's just plain text. Copy & paste the text instead.

Comment: Are you using Python 3? According to [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html), if you want CGI handling, you need to give the `--cgi` option to http.server, like this: `python -m http.server --cgi 8000`

Comment: @PM2Ring: You should put that as an answer. It's clearly better than mine :-)

Answer (score 4):

Are you using Python 3? According to [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html), if you want CGI handling, you need to give the --cgi option to http.server, like this:

```
python -m http.server --cgi 8000
```

Comment: @rsadhvika - This is the right answer. You should accept this answer instead of mine.